# MYSQL terminal Mac command not working 'mysql'

Tags: mysql, command-line, terminal, mamp

I have a hidden file in my home directory called `.profile` with the following:

```
MYSQL_HOME = /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
export PATH=$MYSQL_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The following command works:

```
$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

However `mysql` does not. How can I change the path to make the command work? 
I have MAMP installed, I'm just not sure how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the error is in your first line:

```
   MYSQL_HOME=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

Which should be like this:

```
  MYSQL_HOME=/usr/local/mysql
```

Comment: And remove the spaces around the `=`

Comment: `MYSQL_HOME=/usr/local/mysql/
export PATH=$MYSQL_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Still doesn't work

when i call `echo $PATH` it gives me:
/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Comment: after editing the .profile exit the shell and re-enter. Alternatively do `. <space> ~/.profile` to source the changed path